# Scale tool in Gazebo not working

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am getting started with Gazebo and I am following the "Vehicle construction" tutorial from here:http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?cat=guided_b&tut=guided_b3

I just added a cube shape into the model editor and am having trouble to scaling it graphically with the axis arrows. I can change the visual and collision geometries from the link inspector and it updated the model.

I see this message in the in the terminal that I launched Gazebo from: (not sure if it has anything to do with the scaling)

> Node::Advertise(): Error advertising a topic. Did you forget to start the discovery service?

I am running gazebo on Ubuntu 16.04 in a VM.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19906/scale-tool-in-gazebo-not-working/) by [rakshak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5791/rakshak/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sounds like the same issue as [this question](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/19477/cannot-scaleresize-simple-objects-with-gui-mouse-controls/). There's also an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issues/2487/model-editor-unexpected-behavior) on the repo.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2018-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1